# Hide Menu using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, navigation

Im new to jQuery and need a litte help.

I have created a nav menu that I want to completely disappear upwards after "3 seconds" once  a user lands on the page. From this an arrow will be in its place hiding the original nav menu.

When a user clicks on the "arrow" the menu will come back into view and stay there for now 20 seconds.

I have some code in this jsFiddle but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. Can anyone help out there?

http://jsfiddle.net/headex/AsjMz/1/

Any info passed on will be much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Just a sidenote: <center> is deprecated, see:
http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/appendix/changes.html#h-A.3.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in your live example it's that you're passing the name of the function to the setTimeOut function with `""` in other words

you have this

```
  setTimeout("MenuOut", 3000);
```

Change for this

```
  setTimeout(MenuOut, 3000);
```

Here's your live example with that change [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AsjMz/5/)

Comment: Thank you, it has worked, just need the arrow showing up now! How do I  and add it into the HTML? As an <a> tag with the reference #theButton, similar in the fiddle.

Comment: well in essence to add html to a element you could do it with the function `append()` or `html()` and inject the html that you need in the element that you need

Comment: You have to forgive me Im rather an amateur at this... How would I inject my designed arrow into the append() or html() markers? How would an image with a click sit there?

Comment: let's say that you have your design image in some part of your server, and it's design to be inside a img you could do this: `$('#foo').append('<img 'src="yourPath.jpg"/>')` tried to do it and if you can't oppen a new question. But remember tried to do it first

Comment: Sure thing, I do not want to post a message that has already been answered, but the archives on here are hugeee! Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the correct selectors for your  `<div/>` Elements and supply the `MenuOut()`
 Function as an object, not a string.

```
$(function() {
    setTimeout(MenuOut /*don't supply this parameter as a string*/, 3000); /* 3000 represent 3000 milliseconds, so 3 seconds */
});

function MenuOut() { /* The sample code I put on top */
    $('#nav'/*it's an id (#), here you have to use a string*/).slideUp();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using animate, look at using jQuery's slideUp and slideDown.

You'll want to animate like so: `setTimeout("$('#nav').slideUp()", 3000);`

Answer (score 0):

You had a few errors with your JS. 
setTimeout requires a function callback, not a string. 
You also used $(nav) instead of $("#nav")

http://jsfiddle.net/AsjMz/9/